# Getting error android.content.Context cannot be resolved to a variable?

Tags: android, sdk, connection, android-context

I am trying to develop an android application which connect to SUP2.1.1. I am new to this technology.

```
app.setApplicationContext(android.content.Context);
```

I am getting following error in the above line of code.

```
android.content.Context cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I have added the tools and platform-tools path to the "path" environment variable, and ANDROID_HOME to the user variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to give the class Context as the parameter, but you should give an instance of it.

Comment: Practical implicaton of this correct answer: if you are within an Activity class, the activity itself is a Context instance, so you need to pass `this`... i.e., *app.setApplicationContext(this)*